# GETTING ERROR: No connected devices found; please connect a device, or see flutter.dev/setup for getting started instructions

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am new to android studio. Currently working on a project. But i don't know why I'm continuously getting the error: No connected devices found; please connect a device, or see flutter.dev/setup for getting started instructions, even i have configured a virtual device on my machine. 
Your reply will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you "see at flutter.dev/setup for getting started instructions"?

Comment: did u connect a device?

Comment: Hi @Hack5.. Yes i've checked and followed all the instructions properly.

Comment: Hi @PeterHaddad, i've connected a virtual device..which i even confirmed using flutter doctor.